# Simple derivative of exponential function?

Tags: exponential-function, partial-derivative

$Hello.$
Although I'm not majoring in mathematics but I need some mathematical knowledge to study my major.
Here is a very simple derivative problem of exponential function but I can't find any clues form internet or other basic mathematics books.
$\frac{∂e^{ab}}{∂e^a}=? $
I guess the answer is $e^b$ but not sure and still don't know the logic.
Hope to get any good advice from you guys. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not quite. If $x=e^a$ this is asking for the derivative of $x^b$ with respect to $x$. The answer is therefore $bx^{b-1}$, or $be^{a(b-1)}$.